# init MultipleChoiceField with queryset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.11

In django 1.9 i can init MultipleChoiceField with

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    city = forms.MultipleChoiceField()
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].choices = City.objects.values_list('id', 'name')
        self.initial['city'] = \
            City.objects.filter(some_flag=True).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

In django 1.11 it doesn't work because I have to put tuple or list on Queryset

```
self.initial['city'] = \
    list(City.objects.filter(some_flag=True).values_list('id', flat=True))
```

I found out, that django.forms.widgets has new class ChoiceWidget with method format_value

```
def format_value(self, value):
    """Return selected values as a list."""
    if not isinstance(value, (tuple, list)):
        value = [value]
    return [force_text(v) if v is not None else '' for v in value]
```

Why? In my opinion checking Iterable is better way,

EDIT: Iterable can mess with strings. So we can check if value is QuerySet too.

```
def format_value(self, value):
    """Return selected values as a list."""
    #from collections import Iterable
    #if not isinstance(value, Iterable):
    from django.db.models.query import QuerySet
    if not isinstance(value, (tuple, list, QuerySet)):
        value = [value]
    return [force_text(v) if v is not None else '' for v in value]
```

So

- solution 1: put list() on queryset with values_list('id', flat=True)
- solution 2: monkey patching Widget for MultipleChoiceField

Or somebody knows another solution?

PS. Yes, I know, that ModelMultipleChoiceField exists but I have above logic for many fields and don't want refactor all code now.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    city = City.objects.all()
    cities = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, required=True, queryset=city)
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('city' )
```

May be try this ?

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Problem is in the initialization of MultipleChoiceField.
QuerySet is example of other iterable structures  like generator or itertools.chain.